# How do I use ReorderableListView, specifically what do I put in "onReorder"

Tags: flutter

I need help understanding how to use this widget. 
Right now I am able to get the items to be draggable, but they do not stay on their new spot. I am certain it is because I am using onReorder wrong, but I cannot find an explanation on how. I do not understand or know what it does, and I just kept trying things until it at least could compile.

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MainScreenState createState() => new MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  Widget build(context) {
    final   List<Widget> reorderList = <Widget>[
   Container(key: Key('1'), child:  Icon(Icons.ac_unit),),
   Container(key: Key('2'), child:  Icon(Icons.access_alarm),),
   Container(key: Key('3'), child:  Icon(Icons.access_time),),
   Container(key: Key('4'), child:  Icon(Icons.accessibility),),
   Container(key: Key('5'), child: Icon(Icons.account_box),),
   Container(key: Key('6'), child:  Icon(Icons.account_balance),),
     ];


    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('test'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
          },
            )
          ],
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(child: SideDrawer(context)),
        body: ReorderableListView(
          onReorder: (reorderList, reorderlist) => reorderList ,
          children: reorderList,

        ));
  }
}
```

The page that leads here for thoroughness is as follows:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  build(context) { 
    return Provider(
      child: MaterialApp(

    theme: themeData,
    title: '',
    home:  MainScreen(),
    onGenerateRoute: routes,

  ),
 );
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, 
I do not understand [the Documentation for ReorderableListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) so please do not just link me there.

Thank you so much for any help, it will all be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Everything you need is here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/reorderable_list_demo.dart). Specifically:

```
  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final Container item = reorderList.removeAt(oldIndex);
      reorderList.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }
```

and insert it as:

```
...
reOrder: _onReorder
...
```

Comment: That link is broken